# How to name the columns in a matrice with a loop?

Tags: r, loops, variables

I want to name the columns of the matrix:

```
B=matrix(runif(100), ncol=10,nrow=10,byrow=TRUE)
```

with a simple loop. For example the 10 columns var_1:var_10.
I found different functions but i am to incompetent to integrate them in each other

Name columns and rows:

```
dimnames(B)=list(c("VP_1",....,"VP_10"),c("Var_1",...,"Var_10"))
```

and the loop function

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  e  <- paste("Var_",i,sep="")
  assign(paste("Var_",i,sep=""),with(C,eval(parse(text=e))))
  }
```

may someone help?

Comment: Why with a loop? You can do `colnames(B) <- paste0("VP_", 1:10)` ?

Comment: If you need `assign()`, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you Ronak. Your advise is very helpfull. But if i want to do it by a loop? Lets say to have more flexibility in naming the variables?